# I want to submit code to the SVN server using Jenkins pipeline and skip certificate authentication

Tags: jenkins, svn, certificate, pipeline, commit

I wrote a script using Jenkins pipeline, which involves pulling code from the SVN server, modifying the content, and then submitting the code. However, now I have encountered a problem where I need to authenticate a certificate. I want to skip the authentication of the certificate. The subversion version of my Jenkins installation is "2.17.0". Below is my script and Jenkins' error log. I hope to receive your guidance, thank you。

```
    pipeline:(         
    `stage('Commit') {
                steps {
                    withCredentials([
                        usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'a80f9a0-f90d-4886-sd90-fsd9f89sd8f', 
                        passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'lhk')]) 
                        {
                            sh "svn add --force ."
                            sh "svn commit --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --trust-server-cert --no-auth-cache --non-interactive 
                            --config-option servers:global:http-library=serf --username lhk --password pass 
                            -m 'Jenkins Pipeline commit, update svn repo'"
                        }
                }
            }
)`
```

[Code segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suM4X.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNZ1M.png)

I tried the following parameters

```
--no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid
--non-interactive --no-auth-cache --config-option servers:global:http-library=serf -m "Commit message"
--non-interactive --trust-server-cert
--trust-server-cert-failurs=es='other,unknown-ca,cn-mistma'
```

But it didn't meet my goal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please DO NOT attach images of errors. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters.  Do not add images unless they add value or the concept cannot be conveyed succinctly in words.